# Фильтрация кастомного ListView из SearchView

Tags: filter, android, java

Мучаю вторые сутки фильтрацию из SearchView (actionbar) в кастомном ListView по полю Zakazchik.getName()... на третьи сутки чувствую не хватит нервов :) Молю о помощи :)

**Имеется:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{
   private ListView list;                    // ListView
   private ArrayAdapter<Zakazchik> adapter;  // Адаптер для наполнения ListView
   private List<Zakazchik> listZakazchik;    // Лист объектов для наполнения через адаптер

   // Переопределяем методы SearchView.OnQueryTextListener
   @Override
   public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
       return false;
   }

   // Переопределяем методы SearchView.OnQueryTextListener
   @Override
   public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
           adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
       return true;
   }

...
   adapter = new MyListAdapter();
   list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewAllCategory);
   list.setAdapter(adapter);
   list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);       // указываем ListView на то, что он фильтруется
}
```

**Класс Zakazchik:**

```
public class Zakazchik {
     private String id;
     private String avatarUrl;
     private String subcategory;
     private String name;

Zakazchik(String id, String avatarUrl, String subcategory, String name){
    this.id = id;
    this.avatarUrl = avatarUrl;
    this.subcategory = subcategory;
    this.name = name;
}
    // Геттеры, сеттеры ...
}
```

**Адаптер с фильтром:**

```
public class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Zakazchik> implements Filterable {

    public MyListAdapter() {
       super(MainActivity.this, R.layout.zakazchik, listZakazchik);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View itemView = convertView;
        if (itemView == null) {
            itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.zakazchik, parent, false);
        }

        //Находим заказчика
        Zakazchik currentZakazchik = listZakazchik.get(position);

        //Показываем аватарку (avatarUrl)
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_photo);
        ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        imageLoader.displayImage(currentZakazchik.getAvatarUrl(), imageView);

        //Показываем имя заказчика (name)
        TextView nameText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
        nameText.setText(currentZakazchik.getName());

        //Показываем название подкатегории (subcategory)
        tv_item_subcategory.setText(currentZakazchik.getSubcategory());

        return itemView;
    }

    //***************ФИЛЬТР

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter filter = new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults result = new FilterResults();
                List<Zakazchik> allZakazchik = listZakazchik;
                if(constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0){

                    result.values = allZakazchik;
                    result.count = allZakazchik.size();
                }else{
                    ArrayList<Zakazchik> filteredList = new ArrayList<Zakazchik>();
                    for(Zakazchik j: allZakazchik){
                        if(j.getName().contains(constraint))
                            filteredList.add(j);
                    }
                    result.values = filteredList;
                    result.count = filteredList.size();
                }

                return result;
            }
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results){
                if (results.count == 0) {
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    listZakazchik = (ArrayList<Zakazchik>) results.values;
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }

        };

        return filter;
    }
}
```

**В ActionBar установлен SearchView:** `app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"`

**В MainActivity в onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) определен SearchView со слушателем нажатий:**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     ...
     MenuItem searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menuSearch);
     SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchMenuItem);
     searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
     ...
}
```

**Ругается на строчку**

```
        Zakazchik currentZakazchik = listZakazchik.get(position);
```

java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 4, size is 4

ps. Было замечено, что при попытке ввести в SearchView букву (например О), ListView успевает до вылета приложения отфильтровать себя по этой букве... отображает имена, в которых эта О содержится... и сразу вылетает.

Comment: попробуйте переопределить getCount() у адаптера, чтобы он возвращал длину отфильтрованных

Comment: ПЕРЕСТАЛО вылетать! )))))))))))
Но теперь при вводе букв фильтруется список, а когда убираю в поиске по одной букве - не возвращает позиции по совпадению... и когда строка перестает совпадать - остаются в списке последние совпавшие позиции...

Comment: @Чекист    

     if (results.count == 0) {
         notifyDataSetChanged();
     }

Вы же не обновляете результаты тут, когда их 0. Просто непонятно зачем делаете тут notifyDataSetChanged    

Сделайте так: 
   
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results){
                    listZakazchik = (ArrayList<Zakazchik>) results.values;
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

Comment: Исправил, спасибо. Результат тот же - во время ввода символа список фильтруется, но при удалении последнего символа - не меняется :((

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Инициализируем List, в который поместим данные из ListView (НЕ изменяемый, с ним будем потом сравнивать):

```
private List<Zakazchik> allZakazchik;
```

После заполнения listZakazchik создать новый ArrayList и скопировать туда listZakazchik:

```
this.allZakazchik = new ArrayList<Zakazchik>(listZakazchik);
```

Ну и сам переделанный фильтр:

```
@Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter filter = new Filter() {

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults result = new FilterResults();
                //allZakazchik = new ArrayList(listZakazchik);
                if(constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0){
                    result.values = allZakazchik;
                    result.count = allZakazchik.size();
                }else{
                    filteredList = new ArrayList<Zakazchik>();
                    for(Zakazchik z: allZakazchik){
                        if(z.getName().toLowerCase().contains(constraint))
                            filteredList.add(z);
                        else if (z.getSubcategory().toLowerCase().contains(constraint))
                            filteredList.add(z);
                    }
                    result.values = filteredList;
                    result.count = filteredList.size();
                }
                return result;
            }

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                listZakazchik = (ArrayList<Zakazchik>) results.values;

                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
        return filter;
    }
```

Надо было всего лишь подумать... как обычно :) Но код рабочий, и поиск выполняется динамически.

P.S. Ответ можно пометить как правильный. Спасибо.

Comment: @Чекист, ежели сюда модер не заглянет и не примет ответ, то его вы сами сможете принять чрез 2-а дня.